# Deactivation of the possibility to deactivate 2FA via rescue mode (linux)

Tags: ubuntu, security, two-factor-authentication

Tests 2FA solution for login verification via google PAP module

I have read that this can be easily switched off via rescue mode. Is it possible to disable this solution in case someone has physical access to the machine. So that the 2FA is always active

Comment: Sure just use full-disk encryption with Secure Boot and TPM unlock.

Answer (score 0):

If someone have physical access to machine he/she can do anything. AFAIK nothing can stop him/her to make the changes.

Comment: which means that we have basically just debunked the myth of all these safeguards and appearances of being able to do something. 

in the end, all it takes is a backdoor and we can shove all these pseudo-security-solutions up our arses

Comment: @SantaMonica, we talk about physical access, right?

Comment: assuming that the new boards and cpu have a so-called "god mode" - amt etc it can be assumed that a potential hole or bad guy has "physical access too" in this way, am I wrong?

Comment: @SantaMonica, can be. But I see too many if's :)

Comment: so is there a solution or not?

Comment: @SantaMonica, it depend of who want to access your server. All is about time and money.